# Problem with the comparison function, I think it's not reading all the sample correctly. Any tips?

Tags: python, numpy, counter, image-recognition

I'm very noob at image recognition but was following sendtex's video series. The program worked up until video 9/10 where a function is built to compare sample images to the image being assessed. Here's the video ->  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ry9AzwTMwJQ

I think the problem might be in the "whatNumIsThis" function. I tested the Counter tool shown at 15:53 in the video and the counter works fine. It might be a problem appending the variable "matchedAr" with the variable "currentNum". Or a problem with another one of the variables in that function, I tested the other functions up to that point just printing results at every step and they worked correctly.

```py
def whatNumIsThis(filePath):
    matchedAr = []
    loadExamps = open('numArEx.txt','r').read()
    loadExamps = loadExamps.split('\n')

    i = Image.open(filePath)
    iar = np.array(i)
    iarl = iar.tolist()

    inQuestion = str(iarl)

    for eachExample in loadExamps:
        if len(eachExample) > 3:
            splitEx = eachExample.split('::')
            currentNum = splitEx[0]
            currentAr = splitEx[1]

            eachPixEx = currentAr.split('],')

            eachPixInQ = inQuestion.split('],')

            x = 0

            while x < len(eachPixEx):
                if eachPixEx[x] == eachPixInQ[x]:
                    matchedAr.append(int(currentNum))

                x += 1

    print (matchedAr)
    x = Counter(matchedAr)
    print (x)
```

There is no error message, instead it returns a counter of 1s, like this -

```py
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Counter({1: 100})
```

I've checked the numArEx.txt file and it has all the samples it should, not just samples of number "1". I expected it to return a count of all instances of numbers available, not just "1". Not sure what to do.

Comment: really need to se some of the conents of `numArEx.txt ` to be able to tell

Comment: I got that file when I imported things at the start, can't remember which one. There's an image of what it looks like at 9:41 here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKc8gi1muH4

Comment: Each line in numArEx.txt starts something like this: 0::[[[255, 255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0, 255,] etc. This carries on for every numeral 0-9 with 9 samples of each.